# Cannot import chart.js-plugins-annotations

Tags: javascript, npm, chart.js

```
import { annotation, Chart, defaults } from 'chart.js';
```

using this import statement gives this error:

> localhost/:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "chart.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I cannot find a cdn online to import with a script tag like such:

script src="path/to/chartjs-plugin-annotation/dist/chartjs-plugin-annotation.min.js" /script

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a cdn which has the annotation plugin: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/chartjs-plugin-annotation

Since its a different lib you wont be able to import it from the chart.js core lib